# Concatenate variables in R

Tags: r, variables, string-concatenation

I want to create an object in R, which will contain one string, with a few variables (in my case it is file path).  When I try to use paste to concatenate the file paths I can see only one last variable instead of all variables in one string. I use next code:

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(samples))) {
 lib = samples$conditions[i]
 txtFile = file.path(lib, "hits.txt")
 testfiles = paste(txtFile, sep = ',')
}
print(testfiles)
```

and get something like 
cond/hits.txt,

instead of 
cond/hits.txt,cond1/hits.txt,cond2/hits.txt   and so on

Thank you very much for help

Comment: try `testfiles = paste(testfiles,txtFile, sep=",")` with `testfiles <- ""` before the `for` loop

Comment: Does `collapse = ","` instead of `sep = ","` do it?

Comment: Thank you aichao and cimentadaj. it is strange, but when I use sep = ',' I get comma in a front of the string. When I use paste0 I get comma at the end of the string. What should I do to get the string with commas in the right places.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you posted a reproducible example.

Comment: @ulfelder  for example, when I run the code below I'll get 1,2,3,  I don't want the last comma to appear. Thank you very much.   



      test = "" 


for(i in 1:3){  
        test = paste0( test, i, sep = ",")}  
print(test)      


By the way, why I cannot insert code with CTRL+K to the comment?